# Get the latest record from the table using Oracle

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a requirement that, everytime I Insert records for the same `SAP-ID`.

For Ex:- For

```
         A Sap ID, first time I Insert -> ID/OD then
         A Sap ID, Second time I Insert --> RRH then
         A Sap ID, third time I Insert --> Tenancy.
```

So, for Single `A` Sap ID everytime I m inserting new Row.

But what I want is, while getting the data, I want the latest of all the column in one record.

The table name is `TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST`

Below is the description of the table.

```html
Name                          Null     Type           
----------------------------- -------- -------------- 
ID                            NOT NULL NUMBER         
CMP                                    NVARCHAR2(100) 
SAP_ID                                 NVARCHAR2(100) 
ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE                      DATE           
RRH_COUNTCHANGE                        NVARCHAR2(100) 
RRH_CHANGEDDATE                        DATE           
TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE                    NVARCHAR2(100) 
TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE                    DATE           
RFS_DATE                               DATE           
RFE1_DATE                              DATE           
INFRA_PROVIDER                         NVARCHAR2(100) 
IP_COLO_SITEID                         NVARCHAR2(100) 
SITE_NAME                              NVARCHAR2(500) 
R4GSTATE                               NVARCHAR2(100) 
MW_INSTALLED                           NVARCHAR2(100) 
DG_NONDG                               NVARCHAR2(100) 
EB_NONEB                               NVARCHAR2(100) 
TOWER_TYPE                             NVARCHAR2(100) 
VENDOR_CODE                            NVARCHAR2(100) 
RFCDATE                                DATE           
POLITICAL_STATE_NAME                   NVARCHAR2(100) 
POLITICAL_STATE_CODE                   NVARCHAR2(100) 
SITE_DROP_DATE                         DATE           
CITY_NAME                              NVARCHAR2(100) 
NEID                                   NVARCHAR2(100) 
FACILITY_LATITUDE                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
FACILITY_LONGITUDE                     NVARCHAR2(100) 
RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
RJ_JC_NAME                             NVARCHAR2(100) 
RJ_JC_CODE                             NVARCHAR2(100) 
COMPANY_CODE                           NVARCHAR2(100) 
BLCHAIN_RESP_MSG_MASTER                NVARCHAR2(100) 
BLCHAIN_RESP_CODE_MASTER               NVARCHAR2(100) 
SITE_ADDRESS                           CLOB           
BLCHAIN_RESP_MSG_INCREMENTAL           VARCHAR2(100)  
BLCHAIN_RESP_CODE_INCREMENTAL          VARCHAR2(100)  
CREATED_BY                             NVARCHAR2(100) 
CREATED_DATE                           DATE           
SEL_CHANGED_VAL                        NVARCHAR2(100)
```

Here is how it looks like.

[image: Table info]

Please suggest how can I get this.

**UPDATE**

So for the three rows Inserted, I want to get a single record with all the latest of the three records for a single sap id.

I tried with `MTO`'s answer after editing

```html
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY SAP_ID
           ORDER BY ID DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST t
)
WHERE rn = 1
AND SAP_ID = 'I-MU-MUMB-ENB-I595';
```

But I got the `IDOD`, `RRH` as null. Below is the screenshot

[image: MM]

I want all the data of IDOD, RRH and Tenancy with latest record in single row for a single sapid.

Comment: Why the mysql tag if this is about oracle?

Comment: @P.Salmon: removed by editor guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are generating unique `ID` values using a sequence and your process guarantees the order inserted follows the expected `ID_OD`/`RRH`/`Tenancy` hierarchy then you can bypass the hierarchy and just use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY SAP_ID
           ORDER BY ID DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST t
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you want to use the hierarchy then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY SAP_ID
           ORDER BY CASE
                    WHEN tenancy_changeddate IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                    WHEN rrh_changeddate     IS NOT NULL THEN 2
                    WHEN id_od_changeddate   IS NOT NULL THEN 3
                    ELSE 4
                    END,
                    COALESCE( tenancy_changeddate, rrh_changeddate, id_od_changeddate ) DESC,
                    ID DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST t
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

**Update**:

You appear to not want the latest "row" but want to pull data from a combination of different "latest" rows, so you want something like:

```sql
SELECT MAX( id ) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY tenancy_changeddata NULLS FIRST,
                  rrh_changed_date    NULLS_FIRST,
                  id_od_changeddate   NULLS FIRST
       ) AS id,
       MAX( cmp ) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY tenancy_changeddata NULLS FIRST,
                  rrh_changed_date    NULLS_FIRST,
                  id_od_changeddate   NULLS FIRST,
                  id
       ) AS cmp,
       SAP_ID,
       MAX( ID_OD_CHANGECOUNT ) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY id_od_changeddate   NULLS FIRST,
                  id
       ) AS id_od_changecount,
       MAX( ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE ) AS id_od_changeddate,
       MAX( RRH_CHANGECOUNT ) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY rrh_changeddate   NULLS FIRST,
                  id
       ) AS rrh_changecount,
       MAX( RRH_CHANGEDDATE ) AS rrh_changeddate,
       MAX( TENANCY_CHANGECOUNT ) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY tenancy_changeddate   NULLS FIRST,
                  id
       ) AS tenancy_changecount,
       MAX( TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE ) AS tenancy_changeddate
       -- repeat for other columns as per CMP
FROM   TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST
GROUP BY sap_id
```

Comment: perfect MTO, can I add where condition for checking single sapid info ?

Comment: @BN I do not have sufficient context to understand what you are asking in that comment. The query above should work regardless of whether there is a single row per `SAP_ID` or whether there are many rows.

Comment: when I modified your query by adding where condition like this `FROM   TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST t
  WHERE t.SAP_ID='I-MU-MUMB-ENB-I595'` I got only `tenancy` data and other two - IDOD and RRH as blank

Comment: @BN Please help us to help you and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58214465/1509264) your question with a [MRE] including DML statements for some sample data and your expected output as trying to work out what you want from half-formed queries in comments with no data to back it up is not going to be easy.

Comment: sorry, updated with latest and what I want in question

Comment: i will test and let u know

Comment: @BN Please help us to help you and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58214465/1509264) your question with a valid DDL statement for your table and DML statements for your sample data (**NOT** images) so that we have something to test against. Your table is so huge that I am not going to try writing out all that code myself so without something we can run then you are going to have to debug this yourself.

Comment: your latest answer is perfect..the column name was improper, I made it change and its working

Comment: upvoted for now. let me get it done and after that I will accept it as an answer